# What are the security group rules for Amazon RDS dbinstance and EC2 instance over the different VPCs with VPC Peering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

What security group rules should I set for my db instance and my EC2 instance for accessing DB instance from my EC2 instance?

Both are in different VPCs and I used VPC Peering between them.

I did following configuration:

- I created two VPC's
- One is with public subnet and another is with private subnet
- Launch EC2 web instance with public VPC and MySQL db instance with private subnet
- Set VPC peering between them and they both have different security groups
- Created a NAT Gateway in public subnet

So, how should I set both security group rules for establishing connections between them?

Answer (score 1):

You should configure:

- A **security group on the Amazon EC2 instance** (`App-SG`) that permits access to the instance/application as desired
- A **security group on the Amazon RDS DB instance** (`DB-SG`) that permits inbound access on port 3306 for `App-SG`

That is, `DB-SG` should specifically refer to `App-SG` in the inbound rules.

When connecting from the EC2 to the database, make sure you are using the DNS Name of the RDS database. This should resolve to a private IP address.

The NAT Gateway is not required for the above connection.

Comment: ok **Thank you** @JohnRotenstein . Now i am able to connect with my RDS DB instance.